# Maven 3.3.9 exclude transitive dependencies

Tags: dependencies, maven-3

I am trying to exclude all the transitive dependencies for the pom below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>*</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I run:

```
/usr/local/apps/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn eclipse:eclipse -U
```

However it fails with:

```
Failed to retrieve org.restlet.jee:org.restlet-2.3.0
Path to dependency: 
  1) com.test:test:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  2) org.apache.solr:solr-core:jar:5.4.1
  3) org.restlet.jee:org.restlet.ext.servlet:jar:2.3.0
```

I thought that maven 3.3.9 supported wildcards in exclusions of dependencies?

Comment: Why are you running `mvn eclipse:eclipse` ? Use import as Maven Project in Eclipse...

Comment: The problem is based on the plugin cause the plugin itself is solving dependencies which means it does not delegate that to Maven Core..furthermore the maven-eclipse-plugin is also compatible with Maven 2.X which does not has such functionality. Furthermore please be aware of that the [maven-eclipse-plugin is retired](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/).

Comment: +khmarbaise Thanks for the infos.

Comment: +khmarbaise I don't like the eclipse plugins because they're so.slow. but I guess no choice.

Comment: @bananasplit So you prefer getting problems fast over getting solutions slower? Keep in mind that the purpose of the tool is not to be fast, but to make yourself faster by saving your time guiding you and avoiding mistakes.

Comment: Eclipse plugins are just not stable enough, I tried to make it work but it's just too costly in time and energy. I switched to gradle, I'm now very happy.